# parse all data in xml insert to rows and columns using beautifulsoup and convert xml to csv

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working with my script that can extract or compile all of data the from xml to csv, right now my script can run without error but I still need to find a way to get all the data in xml.

My script can able to compile the data and converted to csv but only first data in the xml can extract when the data converted to csv.

May I know what I need to change on my script?

```
columns = ["DESCRIPTION", "PRODUCT", "ID", "STATUS", "TYPE", "DELIVERYTIME", "DELIVERED", "REMARKS", "NUM"]
rows = []

xml_comp = BeautifulSoup(open('SAMPLE-22.xml'), 'xml')

DESCRIPTION = xml_comp.DESCRIPTION
PRODUCT = xml_comp.PRODUCT
ID = xml_comp.ID
STATUS = xml_comp.STATUS
TYPE = xml_comp.TYPE
DELIVERYTIME = xml_comp.DELIVERYTIME
DELIVERED = xml_comp.DELIVERED
REMARKS = xml_comp.DELIVERED
NUM = xml_comp.NUM

rows.append({
        "DESCRIPTION": DESCRIPTION.text,
        "PRODUCT": PRODUCT.text,
        "ID" : ID.text,
        "STATUS": STATUS.text,
        "TYPE": TYPE.text,
        "DELIVERYTIME": DELIVERYTIME.text,
        "DELIVERED": DELIVERED.text,
        "REMARKS": REMARKS.text,
        "NUM": NUM.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

df.to_csv(f"myFileReport.csv")
```

XML DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuerySAMPLEResponse
    xmlns="http://www.sample.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.SAMPLE.com/2000/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2000-98-01T12:14:27+0" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" rsStart="0">
    <SAMPLEONLYSet>
        <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3894417710">
            <DELIVERYTIME>2000-96-210+0</DELIVERYTIME>
            <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT10</DESCRIPTION>
            <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
            <ID>1000</ID>
            <STATUS>PENDING</STATUS>
            <TYPE>COMP10158533</TYPE>
            <DESCRIPTIONSPEC rowstamp="3853626366">
                <TESTVALUE>TEST-01</TESTVALUE>
                <PRODID>TEST001</PRODID>
            </DESCRIPTIONSPEC>
            <DESCRIPTIONSPEC rowstamp="3853626367">
                <TESTVALUE>PRODUCT 26</TESTVALUE>
                <PRODID>TEST153</PRODID>
            </DESCRIPTIONSPEC>
            <DESCRIPTIONSPEC rowstamp="3853616252">
                <PRODID>TEST418</PRODID>
            </DESCRIPTIONSPEC>
            <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617719">
                <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 25</DESCRIPTION>
                <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
                <ID>1000</ID>
                <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
                <TYPE>COMP10158534</TYPE>
            </DESCRIPTION>
            <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617720">
                <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 24</DESCRIPTION>
                <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
                <ID>1000</ID>
                <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
                <TYPE>COMP10158536</TYPE>
            </DESCRIPTION>
            <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617721">
                <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 23</DESCRIPTION>
                <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
                <ID>1000</ID>
                <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
                <TYPE>COMP10158543</TYPE>
            </DESCRIPTION>
            <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617722">
                <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 22</DESCRIPTION>
                <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
                <ID>1000</ID>
                <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
                <TYPE>COMP10158549</TYPE>
            </DESCRIPTION>
            <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3894417704">
                <DELIVERED>2000-97-230+0</DELIVERED>
                <DELIVERYTIME>2000-96-210+0</DELIVERYTIME>
                <DESCRIPTION> WINDOW TYPE</DESCRIPTION>
                <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
                <NUM>2000-97-240+0</NUM>
                <REMARKS>2000-96-200+0</REMARKS>
                <ID>1000</ID>
                <STATUS>CLOSED</STATUS>
                <TYPE>COMP10158557</TYPE>
            </DESCRIPTION>
            <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3894417711">
                <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT123</DESCRIPTION>
                <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
                <NUM>2000-99-080+0</NUM>
                <REMARKS>2000-96-020+0</REMARKS>
            </DESCRIPTION>
            </SAMPLEONLYSet>
        </QuerySAMPLEONLYResponse>
```

Comment: This markup is not well-formed XML. A few `<DESCRIPTION>` tags do not close. Also, root tags do not match. Please test [mcve] before posting. Does BeautifulSoup not raise an error? Interesting if so.

Answer (score 0):

Since your XML is pretty flat, consider the new [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) (introduced in v1.3) with default `lxml` as parser. This method can even handle default namespaces as included in your markup.

Assuming below fixed markup for proper XML:

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuerySAMPLEResponse xmlns="http://www.sample.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.SAMPLE.com/2000/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2000-98-01T12:14:27+0" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" rsStart="0">
   <SAMPLEONLYSet>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3894417710">
         <DELIVERYTIME>2000-96-210+0</DELIVERYTIME>
         <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT10</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <ID>1000</ID>
         <STATUS>PENDING</STATUS>
         <TYPE>COMP10158533</TYPE>
         <DESCRIPTIONSPEC rowstamp="3853626366">
            <TESTVALUE>TEST-01</TESTVALUE>
            <PRODID>TEST001</PRODID>
         </DESCRIPTIONSPEC>
         <DESCRIPTIONSPEC rowstamp="3853626367">
            <TESTVALUE>PRODUCT 26</TESTVALUE>
            <PRODID>TEST153</PRODID>
         </DESCRIPTIONSPEC>
         <DESCRIPTIONSPEC rowstamp="3853616252">
            <PRODID>TEST418</PRODID>
         </DESCRIPTIONSPEC>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617719">
         <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 25</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <ID>1000</ID>
         <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
         <TYPE>COMP10158534</TYPE>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617720">
         <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 24</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <ID>1000</ID>
         <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
         <TYPE>COMP10158536</TYPE>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617721">
         <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 23</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <ID>1000</ID>
         <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
         <TYPE>COMP10158543</TYPE>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3853617722">
         <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT 22</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <ID>1000</ID>
         <STATUS>COMPLETE</STATUS>
         <TYPE>COMP10158549</TYPE>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3894417704">
         <DELIVERED>2000-97-230+0</DELIVERED>
         <DELIVERYTIME>2000-96-210+0</DELIVERYTIME>
         <DESCRIPTION>WINDOW TYPE</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <NUM>2000-97-240+0</NUM>
         <REMARKS>2000-96-200+0</REMARKS>
         <ID>1000</ID>
         <STATUS>CLOSED</STATUS>
         <TYPE>COMP10158557</TYPE>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <DESCRIPTION rowstamp="3894417711">
         <DESCRIPTION>PRODUCT123</DESCRIPTION>
         <PRODUCT>DESKTOP733</PRODUCT>
         <NUM>2000-99-080+0</NUM>
         <REMARKS>2000-96-020+0</REMARKS>
      </DESCRIPTION>
   </SAMPLEONLYSet>
</QuerySAMPLEResponse>
```

**Python**

```py
description_df = pd.read_xml(
   xml, xpath=".//doc:SAMPLEONLYSet/doc:DESCRIPTION", namespaces={"doc": "http://www.sample.com"}
))

description_df
#      rowstamp   DELIVERYTIME  DESCRIPTION     PRODUCT      ID    STATUS          TYPE  DESCRIPTIONSPEC      DELIVERED            NUM        REMARKS
# 0  3894417710  2000-96-210+0    PRODUCT10  DESKTOP733  1000.0   PENDING  COMP10158533              NaN           None           None           None
# 1  3853617719           None   PRODUCT 25  DESKTOP733  1000.0  COMPLETE  COMP10158534              NaN           None           None           None
# 2  3853617720           None   PRODUCT 24  DESKTOP733  1000.0  COMPLETE  COMP10158536              NaN           None           None           None
# 3  3853617721           None   PRODUCT 23  DESKTOP733  1000.0  COMPLETE  COMP10158543              NaN           None           None           None
# 4  3853617722           None   PRODUCT 22  DESKTOP733  1000.0  COMPLETE  COMP10158549              NaN           None           None           None
# 5  3894417704  2000-96-210+0  WINDOW TYPE  DESKTOP733  1000.0    CLOSED  COMP10158557              NaN  2000-97-230+0  2000-97-240+0  2000-96-200+0
# 6  3894417711           None   PRODUCT123  DESKTOP733     NaN      None          None              NaN           None  2000-99-080+0  2000-96-020+0
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your input @Parfait, May I know what I need to modify my script to make it work? after I add this on my script I encountered an error in **rows.append({
        "DESCRIPTION": DESCRIPTION.text** part. apologize, currently I just start learning python script with xml thats why I'm not so familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, with your implementation, you only receive the first set of data because you are not iterating through all `<DESCRIPTION>` elements. Usually parsed data will return as an iterable like list.

Additionally, in your learning curve of Python and XML, consider a more Pythonic and XML parsing approach which includes:

- Use a conformant XML library such as the built-in [**`etree`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or third-party [**`lxml`**](https://lxml.de/) which helps handle default namespaces as your current XML contains. In fact, `BeautifulSoup` defaults to `lxml` under the hood.
- Use a defined namespace prefix to parse nodes under default namespace. See `namespaces` argument of lxml's [`xpath`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) or etree's [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall).
- Use [list/dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) rather than the bookkeeping of initializing list and appending items.
- Avoid repetitive code with defined methods such as parsing text on optional nodes that may not exist across all `<DESCRIPTION>` elements. Per your error, you receive `.text` can only be available if element exists, so check if node exists prior to parsing text.
- Use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (or ternary operator) to concisely assign a value like checking existence of element.

```py
import pandas as pd
import lxml.etree as lx

doc = lx.parse('SAMPLE-22.xml')
nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.sample.com"}

# DEFINED METHOD (WITH CONDITIONAL EXPRESSION) TO EXTRACT ELEMENT TEXT
def get_xml_text(row, node):
    return (
        row.find(node, namespaces=nmsp).text 
        if row.find(node, namespaces=nmsp) is not None 
        else None
    )

# BUILD LIST OF DICTIONARIES
rows = [
    {
        "DESCRIPTION": get_xml_text(row, "doc:DESCRIPTION"),
        "PRODUCT": get_xml_text(row, "doc:PRODUCT"),
        "ID": get_xml_text(row, "doc:ID"),
        "STATUS": get_xml_text(row, "doc:STATUS"),
        "TYPE": get_xml_text(row, "doc:TYPE"),
        "DELIVERYTIME": get_xml_text(row, "doc:DELIVERYTIME"),
        "DELIVERED": get_xml_text(row, "doc:DELIVERED"),
        "REMARKS": get_xml_text(row, "doc:REMARKS"),
        "NUM": get_xml_text(row, "doc:NUM")
    }
    for row in doc.xpath(
        ".//doc:SAMPLEONLYSet/doc:DESCRIPTION", namespaces=nmsp
    )
]

# BIND LIST INTO DATA FRAME
description_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output**

```
print(description_df)

#    DESCRIPTION     PRODUCT    ID  ...      DELIVERED        REMARKS            NUM
# 0    PRODUCT10  DESKTOP733  1000  ...           None           None           None
# 1   PRODUCT 25  DESKTOP733  1000  ...           None           None           None
# 2   PRODUCT 24  DESKTOP733  1000  ...           None           None           None
# 3   PRODUCT 23  DESKTOP733  1000  ...           None           None           None
# 4   PRODUCT 22  DESKTOP733  1000  ...           None           None           None
# 5  WINDOW TYPE  DESKTOP733  1000  ...  2000-97-230+0  2000-96-200+0  2000-97-240+0
# 6   PRODUCT123  DESKTOP733  None  ...           None  2000-96-020+0  2000-99-080+0
```

---

Just recently learned about [**`findtext`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext) which avoids the conditional expression!

```py
rows = [
    {
        "DESCRIPTION": row.findtext("doc:DESCRIPTION", namespaces=nmsp),
        "PRODUCT": row.findtext("doc:PRODUCT", namespaces=nmsp),
        "ID": row.findtext("doc:ID", namespaces=nmsp),
        "STATUS": row.findtext("doc:STATUS", namespaces=nmsp),
        "TYPE": row.findtext("doc:TYPE", namespaces=nmsp),
        "DELIVERYTIME": row.findtext("doc:DELIVERYTIME", namespaces=nmsp),
        "DELIVERED": row.findtext("doc:DELIVERED", namespaces=nmsp),
        "REMARKS": row.findtext("doc:REMARKS", namespaces=nmsp),
        "NUM": row.findtext("doc:NUM", namespaces=nmsp),
    }
    for row in doc.xpath(
        ".//doc:SAMPLEONLYSet/doc:DESCRIPTION", namespaces=nmsp
    )
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```